# Promise Resolve Object giving empty Object

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

so in my Node file, I take some data from a Mongoose database, perform some operations and I want a dictionary like object at the end. Now my Mongoose database has only two objects I want, so I use the `aggregate` command to give me those. Then, I loop through the results, and add them to a dictionary. Then, I want to display something from the dictionary. Due to the asynchronous nature of all this, I was forced to learn/use promises. Therefore, this is the code that I generated:

```
function f1(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{    
        collectionName.aggregate([
        {
            $group:
                {
                _id: "$ids",
                property: {$max: "$properties"}
                }
            }
    ]).then(data=>{
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            dictionary[data[i]['_id']] = data[i]['property'];
        }
    });
    resolve(dictionary);
    });

    };

async function f2(){
    var dict = await f1()
    console.log(dict)

f1();
f2();
```

when I put a console.log into the for loop, I get the data I want in that it has the id and the property in dictionary form. However, when I run f2, I only get `{}` as the output. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `resolve(dictionary)` being outside of the `aggregate()` 's `then()`, it executes before `dictionary` is populated, hence the empty object. Try moving the `resolve(dictionary)` to inside the `then()` of `aggregate()` instead to return a promise with value of `dictionary`. Effectively you are attempting to [chain promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining). Make sure to also return the `collectionName.aggregate()` as a whole as well to ensure the entire promise is returned from `f1()`.

```
function f1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    return collectionName.aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: "$ids",
        property: {
          $max: "$properties"
        }
      }
    }]).then(data => {
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dictionary[data[i]['_id']] = data[i]['property'];
      }

      return resolve(dictionary);
    });
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: it was that simple...just for understanding though, shouldn't I resolve the promise on the same level (i.e. outside the then) that I called it? I can't seem to comprehend why it should be inside the then

Comment: This is simply an issue of execution timing. The `resolve(dictionary)` was executing before function `aggregate()` resolved. Returning the `resolve(dictionary)` inside the `then()` returns a resolved promise once `aggregate()` has successfully resolved.